# ObjectCache and how it works

Tags: c#, .net, caching

Following c# code is a stripped version of what I have. This basically cache data using `memory cache` and the `AbsoluteExpiration` values decides when to clear the cache. All works as expected. However, recently, I had to include following code within a `singleton` data structure. This left me with some questions;

1. how/who initiate cache clearing
   process when cache expire?
2. how it works in multi-threaded scenario,
   when my singleton object is accessed parallely?

   > ```
   > ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
   > if (cache.Contains(”UniqueKey”))
   > return cache.Get(”UniqueKey”);    
   > var dataToCache = GetData();//This is the data that I cache
   > var policy = new CacheItemPolicy {AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheExpiry"]))};
   > cache.Add(”UniqueKey”, dataToCache, policy);
   > return dataToCache;
   > ```

Comment: In multithreaded scenario you probably need to use locks when accessing your cache. When cache expires it will expire, what do you mean by clearing process?

Comment: lock doesn't suffice the purpose. Expire means, when the AbsoluteExpiration elapse.